# Why does gdal_grid turn image upside-down?

Tags: python, grid, gis, gdal

I'm trying to use gdal_grid to make an elevation grid from a surface in a geojson. I use this command:

```
gdal_grid -a linear:radius=0 inputSurface.geojson outputFile.tif
```

It seems to give the correct pixel values, but if I open the result in Global Mapper or QGIS, the image is flipped/mirrored in a horizontal axis, such that the tif is directly below the surface and upside-down.
What is the reason for this and how do I fix it??

**Update**

I already tried changing the geotransform, but it hasn't totally fixed my problem.

I looked at the resulting image in gdalinfo and found out that the upper left corner is actually the lower left corner, so I set it using the SetGeoTransform. This moved it to the correct location, but it is still upside-down. (This may by dependent on the projection, which might cause problems later)

I also tried looking at the pixel width in the geotransform as mentioned below:

```
Xgeo = GT[0] + Xpixel*GT[1] + Yline*GT[2]
Ygeo = GT[3] + Xpixel*GT[4] + Yline*GT[5]
```

The image returned by gdal_grid has a positive GT[5], but unfortunately changing it to -GT[5] doesn't change anything.

The code I used to change the geotransform:

```
transform = list(ds.GetGeoTransform())
transform = [upperLeftX, transform[1], 0, upperLeftY, 0, -transform[5]]
ds.SetGeoTransform(transform)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up having more problems with gdal_grid, where it just crashes at seemingly random places, so I'm using the scipy.interpolate-function called griddata in stead. This uses a meshgrid to get the coordinates in the grid, and I had to tile it up because of memory restrictions of meshgrid.

```
import scipy.interpolate as il #for griddata
import numpy as np
# meshgrid of coords in this tile
gridX, gridY = np.meshgrid(xi[c*tcols:(c+1)*tcols], yi[r*trows:(r+1)*trows][::-1])

## Creating the DEM in this tile
zi = il.griddata((coordsT[0], coordsT[1]), coordsT[2], (gridX, gridY),method='linear',fill_value = nodata) # fill_value to prevent NaN at polygon outline
raster.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(zi,c*tcols,nrows-r*trows-rtrows)
```

The linear interpolation seems to do the same as gdal_grid is supposed to. This was actually effected by making the 5'th element in the geotransform negative as described in the question update.

See description at [scipy.interpolate.griddata](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html).

A few things to note:

1. The point used in the geotransform should be upper-left
2. The resolution in y-direction should be negative
3. In the projection (at least the ones I use) positive y-direction is up
4. In numpy arrays positive y-direction is down
5. When using gdal's WriteArray it uses the upper left corner

Hope this helps other people's confusion.

Answer (score 1):

GDAL's georeferencing is commonly specified by two sets of parameters. The first is the spatial reference, which defines the coordinate system (UTM, WGS, something more localized). The spatial reference for a raster is set using `gdal.Dataset.setProjection()`. The second piece of georeferencing is the GeoTransform, which translates (row, column) pixel indices into coordinates in the coordinate system. It is likely the geotransform that you need to update to make your image "unflipped".

The GeoTransform is a tuple of 6 values, which relate raster indices into coordinates.

```
Xgeo = GT[0] + Xpixel*GT[1] + Yline*GT[2]
Ygeo = GT[3] + Xpixel*GT[4] + Yline*GT[5]
```

Because these are raster images, the (line, pixel) or (row, col) coordinates start from the top left of the image.

```
[ ]----> column
 |
 |
 v row
```

This means that `GT[1]` will be positive when the image is positioned "upright" in the coordinate system. Similarly, and sometimes counter-intuitively, `GT[5]` will be negative because the y value should decrease for every increasing row in the image. This isn't a requirement, but it is very common.

#### Modifying the GeoTransform

You state that the image is upside down and below where is should be. This isn't guaranteed to be a fix, but it will get you started. It's easier if you have the image in front of you and can experiment or compare coordinates...

```
import gdal
# open dataset as readable/writable
ds = gdal.Open('input.tif', gdal.GA_Update)
# get the GeoTransform as a tuple
gt = gdal.GetGeoTransform()
# change gt[5] to be it's negative, flipping the image
gt_new = (gt[0], gt[1], gt[2], gt[3], gt[4], -1 * gt[5])
# set the new GeoTransform, effectively flipping the image
ds.SetGeoTransform(gt_new)
# delete the dataset reference, flushing the cache of changes
del ds
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately changing gt[5] to be negative doesn't seem to change anything (see update)

Answer (score 0):

I've solved a similar issue by simply re-projecting the results of the gdal_grid. Give this a try (replacing the epsg code with your projection and replacing the input/output filepaths):

`gdalwarp -s_srs epsg:4326 -t_srs epsg:4326 gdal_grid_result.tif inverted_output.tif`

Answer (score 0):

it does not. it is simply the standards of the tool rendering it. try opening it in QGIS and youll notice it is right side up.